# In bootstrap grid system how would I transform a column into a row on some viewport

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**What I am trying to do?**

On > 580px viewport I have a row in the footer with three columns and On <= 580px I want to have only two columns and want the last column to be transformed into a new row. I realised this can only be done with jQuery.

**What Is the problem ?**

For some reason bootstrap seems to add padding-right to the body on <= 580px.

**What I have tried ?**

1. I tried adding negative padding and margin.
2. Tried to place the new row inside a container.

**My Code:**

```js
var extraSmallDeviceReached = false;

function adjustFooterOnMobile() {

  function toDefault() {
    $('.follow, .resources').removeClass('col-xs-6');
    $('.briefDescrp').removeClass('row');
    $('.briefDescrp div').removeClass('col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11');
    $('.follow, .resources, .briefDescrp').addClass('col-xs-4');
  }

  function onExtraSmallDevices() {
    $('.resources, .follow, .briefDescrp').removeClass('col-xs-4');
    $('.resources, .follow').addClass('col-xs-6');
    $('.briefDescrp').addClass('row');
    $('.briefDescrp div').addClass('col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11');
  }

  if ($(window).width() < 581) {
    onExtraSmallDevices();
    extraSmallDeviceReached = true;
  } else if (extraSmallDeviceReached)
    toDefault();
}
adjustFooterOnMobile();
$(window).resize(function() {
  adjustFooterOnMobile();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 resources">
        <h3> Resources </h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li> <a href="#">&nbsp; a </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">&nbsp; b </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">&nbsp; c </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 follow">
        <h3> Follow </h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#"> &nbsp; x </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">&nbsp; y </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">> &nbsp; z </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 briefDescrp">
        <div>
          <h3> Brief Description </h3>
          <hr>
          <p><strong> efgh.</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: how are you calling that function `adjustFooterOnMobile `

Comment: i ran that code but i couldn't find any `padding` on body element, could you give me also the css file ?

Comment: @Ashishsah Edited my post have a look.

Comment: can you upload your code on js bin?

Comment: Guys I think fixed the problem. I just removed the added row and I changed the `col-xs-6` to `col-xs-5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found a fix**

**By changing this:**

```
function toDefault() {
   $('.follow, .resources').removeClass('col-xs-6'); # change to col-xs-5
   $('.briefDescrp').removeClass('row'); # remove this
   $('.briefDescrp div').removeClass('col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11'); # remove 'div'
   $('.follow, .resources, .briefDescrp').addClass('col-xs-4');
}

function onExtraSmallDevices() {
   $('.resources, .follow, .briefDescrp').removeClass('col-xs-4');
   $('.resources, .follow').addClass('col-xs-6'); # change to col-xs-5
   $('.briefDescrp').addClass('row'); # remove this
   $('.briefDescrp div').addClass('col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11'); # remove 'div'
}
```

**To this:**

```
function toDefault() {
    $('.follow, .resources').removeClass('col-xs-5');
    $('.briefDescrp').removeClass('col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11');
    $('.follow, .resources, .briefDescrp').addClass('col-xs-4');
}

function onExtraSmallDevices() {
    $('.resources, .follow, .briefDescrp').removeClass('col-xs-4');
    $('.resources, .follow').addClass('col-xs-5');
    $('.briefDescrp').addClass('col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without jquery.
   According to your HTML code please put the following CSS at the end of your stylesheet.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:580px) {
 footer .col-xs-4     {width:50%!important;}
}
```

Comment: do you want the 3rd column to be full width after it drops down, at window width less  than 580 view ?

Comment: Yeah absolutely.

Comment: I do that with `$('.briefDescrp div').addClass('col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11');` in my jQuery function.

Comment: can you try this code?     footer .row > div:last-child {width:100%!important}

Comment: I did that but I still get the padding. And the last column doesn't span the whole width.

Comment: I think fixed the problem. I just removed the added row and I changed the col-xs-6 to col-xs-5.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of col-xs-{size} in Bootstrap 4 you need to use col-{size}

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 resources">
        <h3> Resources </h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li> <a href="#">&nbsp; a </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">&nbsp; b </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">&nbsp; c </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 follow">
        <h3> Follow </h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#"> &nbsp; x </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">&nbsp; y </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">> &nbsp; z </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 briefDescrp">
        <h3> Brief Description </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I am not using bootstrap 4. I use bootstrap 3.

Comment: And why your snippet is using bootstrap 4? :)

Comment: I didn't created the snippet. someone else edit my question.

Comment: Oh well, actually there is no breakpoint at 580px in bootstrap 3, i can suggest you to migrate to bootstrap 4. An other way should be to edit the grid.less file and add your custom breakpoint. Ps: using jquery for just layout fixing things is not worth for me!

Comment: I replaced the `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` from 3 to 4. But I still noticed the padding-right to body.

Comment: Bootstrap add 15px of padding left and right to cols and container... If you have some other unwanted padding on the body it came from an other source